# content_scripts fails to load Url on one particular website

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am sorry if that is something obvious.  I am pretty new to Chrome extensions development.
Here is a weird problem I am having.  Cannot find anything similar in searches.
My extension creates an iframe with a menu to display on every page.  It works fine everywhere except this one particular site (https://www.td.com/ca/en/business-banking/small-business/)
On that site my html for the iframe doesn't load at all, iframe is empty when added to the website.
Here is short version of my manifest:

```
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "1.0",
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "run_at": "document_idle",
      "matches": ["*://*/*", "file:///"],
      "js": ["js/content_script.js"]
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "inj.html"
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "storage",
    "chrome://favicon/",
    "activeTab",
    "webNavigation"
  ]
```

This is the code I am executing in content_script.js

```
  iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
  iframe.id = "my_iframe";
  iframe.style.overflow = "auto";
  iframe.style.height = "100vh";
  iframe.style.width = 0;
  iframe.style.position = "fixed";
  iframe.style.top = "0px";
  iframe.style.right = "0px";
  iframe.style.zIndex = "9999999999";
  iframe.style.border = 0;
  iframe.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("../inj.html");
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

It works in 99% of the cases, except this one website.  Makes me wonder if I am missing something important.
Any ideas would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: See if `chrome://policy` has ExtensionSettings with runtime_blocked_hosts that matches this site.

Comment: I don't see anything relevant there, no policies set there.  I also other extensions seem to be running fine on that site.  Must be something I am doing wrong.

Comment: The only weird thing is `../` in the URL, it's invalid strictly speaking, but I guess it's simply ignored so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I tried with and without it.  It works find on all other sites either way.

Answer (score 0):

So, after some really painful hours, I found that for some websites it is necessary to have a timeout before setting the src on the newly created iframe.
The following works fine:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    iframe.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("../inj.html");
  }, 500);
```